# How to join the rectangles in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I have a question about how to join the rectangles so that they become another shape?
I have created `rectangle/2` facts such as:

```
rectangle(1.14, 2.14).    %rectangle(Length, Width).
rectangle(1.36, 3.34).
rectangle(0.20, 2.35).
rectangle(1.00, 1.30).
```

But, are these facts correct anyway?

[Here](http://postimage.org/image/u7g22p1wv/) is the image I want to create and [this](http://postimage.org/image/uy8s8h4a7/) is the image detailing how the rectangles are combined.

The rectangles should joined using the selected edge.

Comment: Try to add the meaning of a `rectangle/2` fact, ie: the first argument means ___ and the second argument means ___. Try to precise what you mean by joining shapes too. How should the result look like? Should it be coordinates or something else? If you have more infos, add them, atm what you are trying to achieve is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two numbers do not constitute a rectangle because a rectangle has 4 points.

Start by trying to build clauses with 4 arguments like this:

```
rectangle(X1/Y1, X2/Y2, ..).
```

Then you may query the points as such:

```
?- rectangle(X1/Y2,_,_,_).
X1 = 42
Y1 = 42
```

So you'd need to infer the actual rectangles from the points given, or you need the assert the rectacle/4 predicates when building your code.

Comment: I disagree with **a rectangle has 4 points.** A rectangle has addictional constraints, and using 4 points easily overcome them. Add `x,y` as top left origin point to your original representation, instead. That's for instance the representation that SVG uses.